# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message) running from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Trying to run application on:

- Samsung Galaxy S3
- LG-K430
- Nexus 5
- Meizu M2 Note

On all the devices I can't run application with error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForAlphaDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
```

What I tried to do:

- Restarted Macbook
- Removed Android Studio completely and installed latest one (v3.5.3)
- Clean and rebuild

However, everything works fine when I install the same code on the same devices from `Fabric Beta` and `Firebase App Tester`.
Also, everything works fine from Android Studio on the following devices:

- Oneplus 3
- Samsung S10
- Google Pixel

Would really appreciate all the help that you can provide!

Comment: Are you sure that everything works from Fabric and Firebase App tester? Are they the exact same snapshots of your code? If so, you can try installing the app from your terminal using `./gradlew app:installDebug`. If it's an Android studio issue, then the command should succeed, otherwise it might be a misconfiguration in your build files.

Comment: if you already have gradle wrapper, then simply writing `gradle app:installDebug` does the trick. It helped me install my app successfully, idk why it wouldn't do it through AS...